# In-call status bar overlaps with presenting view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, uistatusbar, in-call

Say I have just 3 controllers `FirstViewController`, `SecondViewController` and a `RootViewController`.

And I present `FirstViewController` from `RootViewController`, and then `SecondViewController` from `FirstViewController` on some Button's tap, so the controller's hierarchy will look like this:

```
RootViewController --> FirstViewController --> SecondViewController
```

Now when I show `in-call status bar` using simulator's `Toggle In-call status bar` option while `SecondViewController` is on-screen, and get back to `FirstViewController` by dismissing it, `FirstViewController`'s View does not shift down and thus `Green status bar` overlaps the controller's view.

**Do you guys have any idea like how to handle this scenario? or Do we really need to manually adjust the View frame?**

**Note:**

1) I am trying this scenario with demo app, so I have no complex code.

2) Also I found a strange behaviour that, if I show `in-call status bar` from `FirstViewController` and get back to `RootViewController`, it does not mess-up the root controller's layout and it's view shifts down correctly (`RootViewController` is in storyboard while `FirstViewController` and `SecondViewController` have separate XIBs).

**Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.**